# Dataproc version upgrade:Classloader is expected to be an instance of URLClassLoader

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

We have been running Cloud Data Fusion pipelines on CDF 6.8.2 and Dataproc 2.0.79-debian10. As Dataproc image 2.0 is running out of support, we are trying to upgrade Dataproc alone to 2.1.35-debian11, but not Datafusion. While running the same pipeline on new Dataproc version, job fails to start on Dataproc with the following error. Looks to be a java compatibility issue. Is there a way to get these versions work with some additional arguments?

2023-12-22 00:10:28,817 ERROR runtimejob.DataprocJobMain: Uncaught exception from thread Thread[main,5,main]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.shim.HadoopRunClassShim.main(HadoopRunClassShim.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Classloader is expected to be an instance of URLClassLoader
at io.cdap.cdap.runtime.spi.runtimejob.DataprocJobMain.main(DataprocJobMain.java:94)
... 5 more

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I find CDF 6.8.2 doesn't support Dataproc 2.1 as an execution engine. It is supported only starting 6.9.1 https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/CDAP-20543